# Polymer not working on iOS even with polyfills included

Tags: ios, polymer, mobile-safari, polymer-1.0, polyfills

I'm trying to run my Polymer 1.0 app in Safari on iOS 9.1 but it just doesn't render anything.  Even with

```
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
```

as my first import in the head tag. I tried checking logs with remote console and this is what I've got:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$.mq')
```

which is fired on the third line in this function:

```
  _forceNarrowChanged: function() {
    // set the narrow mode only if we reached the `responsiveWidth`
    this._responsiveChange(this.forceNarrow || this.$.mq.queryMatches);
  },
```

And this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$.mainContainer')
```

which is fired somewhere in webcomponents library.

Also WebComponentsReady event is fired (tested with a debug console log statement).

I'm using vulcanize grunt task to inline all the scripts and styles into one html file. Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I tried serving polymer starter kit with gulp and it worked. I will try to disable parts of my app to isolate the problem.

**Update 2**: I managed to resolve the issue by moving all the bower_components from polymer starter kit into my projects, seems to be the bug fixed in a newer version or something like that.

Comment: Can you give more codedetails about the polymer element causing the bug

Comment: First js error described in question is in the paper-drawer-panel's code.

Comment: Can you post your update as an answer?  That would better fit the format of this site.